# -su: syntax error near unexpected token '('

Tags: shell, ubuntu, postgresql-9.5

I'm getting the error:

```
-su: syntax error near unexpected token '(`
```

This is when I run the script in shell:

```
psql -c CREATE TABLE test1 (device SERIAL)
```

If however I am already in postgres and I run the command below to create a table it works,

```
CREATE TABLE test (device SERIAL)
```

Does anyone know how I can fix the problem? Thank you

Comment: `psql -c 'CREATE TABLE test1 (device SERIAL)'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to quote the command you want to execute.

```
psql -c "CREATE TABLE test1 (device SERIAL)"
```

or

```
psql -c 'CREATE TABLE test1 (device SERIAL)'
```

Otherwise Shell parses the command differently and tries to use every space separated token as another argument:

```
psql -c CREATE ...Gibberish other arguments psql does not understand...
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, what happens if I want to create multiple tables so one table as test1 and another as test2. Am I able to put a variable in there like test$i so I can do it in a for loop?

Comment: @Mark Yes, but then you need double quotes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash

Comment: You can create multiple tables this way, just use standard sql syntax separating commands with a semicolon `;`